# Oracle Forms 10g Copy command

Tags: copy, command, oracleforms

I am using oracle 10g forms. I want to copy a image saved in my PC to server. While I checked locally by using two destination of my pc it works fine.

Code is

```
the_command:= 'copy D:\WORKORDER\'||:title.filename||'_'||:title.page||'.jpg D:\vish\'||:title.filename||'_'||:title.page||'.jpg';
```

My server is linux based. So I used the command

```
copy D:\WORKORDER\'||:title.filename||'_'||:title.page||'.jpg \WEB\folder\WORK_ORDER\'||:title.filename||'_'||:title.page||'.jpg';
```

It is not copying image in my pc to serverlocation. I tried both forward and backward slashes. Please help

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that you should install **Webutil** and use its `CLIENT_HOST` to do that.

Although Forms offers the `HOST` built-in, as 10g Forms application runs on the Application server, `HOST` affects files **on** the server - not locally, on your PC. Therefore, as I said - Webutil's `CLIENT_HOST`.

Comment: @Vishnu - Forms 10g is web-based, so the forms are run on the web server, and local commands such as `host` are **local to the server**.  To interact between the form on the web server and anything on your desktop you need to use the Oracle Forms Webutils library as suggested here. It has a lot of extensions which provide equivalent functionality for local commands but which work across the network.